# Remove milliseconds from timestamp pyspark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, to-timestamp

I have two fields, both in **string** type. One field is called **date**, the other **time**.

The date field has values like below:
`20220328,20220329,20220330,20220331`

The timefield has values like below:
`043313,045546,043313,044147`

What I need is for these values to be converted to timestamp datatype and thus should look something like this:

```
2022-03-28T04:33:13
2022-03-29T04:55:46
2022-03-30T04:33:13
2022-03-28T04:41:47
```

I have the following code:

```sql
to_timestamp(concat(to_date(table.date,'yyyyMMdd'),COALESCE(nullif(table.time, ''),'000000')) , 'yyyy-MM-ddHHmmss')
```

which works fine, but returns the timestamp like below:
`2022-03-28T04:33:13.000+0000`

Does anyone know how I can remove the trailing `000+0000` so that I would only keep `2022-03-28T04:33:13`?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You want to format the timestamp, you can use [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#date_format) function for that:

```py
spark.sql("""
    select date_format(
                to_timestamp(
                    concat(table.date, coalesce(nullif(table.time, ''), '000000')),
                     'yyyyMMddHHmmss'
                ),
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
            ) as new_date
    from values ('20220328', '043313'), ('20220329', '045546'), ('20220330', '043313'), ('20220331', '044147') as table (date, time)
""").show()

#+-------------------+
#|           new_date|
#+-------------------+
#|2022-03-28T04:33:13|
#|2022-03-29T04:55:46|
#|2022-03-30T04:33:13|
#|2022-03-31T04:41:47|
#+-------------------+
```